# C++ std array of function pointer syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'd like an `std::array` of function pointers. The only similar examples I can find are old-style raw arrays, or `std::array` of `std::function`.

Is it possible to translate this syntax:

```
bool (*arr[2])(int) = { foo, foo2 };
```

declaring an array of 2 functions, taking an int argument and returning a `bool`...

..to use a `std::array`?

Comment: Indeed In C++ don't use function pointers use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), your syntax will be `std::array<std::function<bool(int)>,2ul>`. This will also allow you to use [lambda expressions/functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as arguments too. (Function pointers will work too)

Comment: @PepijnKramer With `std::function()` you'll pay for a virtual call.

Comment: @Evg Exactly (virtual call)......

Comment: @Evg Please put as answer and i'll accept

Comment: @Evg fair enough, I consider it an engineering trade-off. :) (And yes I am aware most of the stuff I write is not exactly time/space limited)

Comment: `std::array<bool(*)(int), 2>` is the poorly readable form.   More readable is to use a type alias (either `using Func = bool(*)(int)` or `typedef bool (*Func)(int)`) and then `std::array<Func, 2>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the [“clockwise/spiral rule”](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), `bool (*)(int)` is a pointer to a function that takes `int` and returns `bool`, so:

```
std::array<bool (*)(int), 2> arr = { /* ... */ };
```

or with a type alias:

```
using FunPtr = bool (*)(int);
std::array<FunPtr, 2> arr = { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: I'd have put the type alias first; the other version is much harder to read. +1.

Answer (score 3):

With `c++17` and `std::array` you do not even need to care to much about the type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int foo(int f)
{
    return f*f;
}

int bar(int b)
{
    return b*b*b;
}

int main()
{
    std::array arr = {&foo, &bar};
    std::cout << arr[0](6);
    std::cout << arr[1](3);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7qnY4s781

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <array>

// Declare function type
using MyFunctionType = bool(*)(int);

// Sample functions
bool function1(int i) {
    // Function 1 implementation
}

bool function2(int i) {
    // Function 2 implementation
}

void function3() {
    // Function 3 implementation
}

int main() {
    // Declare array of function pointers
    std::array<MyFunctionType, 3> functionArray;

    // Assign functions to array elements
    functionArray[0] = &function1;
    functionArray[1] = &function2;
    functionArray[2] = &function3;

    // Call functions through array
    functionArray[0](1);
    functionArray[1](2);
    functionArray[2](3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::array<MyFunctionType, 3> function Array = { &function1, &function, &function };` should also work.